# No module named'_pydevd_bundle_ext' appears when pycharm connects to the server for debugging

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

No module named'_pydevd_bundle_ext' appears when pycharm connects to the server for debugging, There is no code.py file or code folder in my project

The file name is my_pro.py,my code is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('DD')
    print()
```

My error is

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/www/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_trace_dispatch.py", line 55, in 
from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_cython_wrapper import trace_dispatch as _trace_dispatch, global_cache_skips, global_cache_frame_skips, fix_top_level_trace_and_get_trace_func
File "/home/www/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_wrapper.py", line 48, in 
raise exc
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/www/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 49, in 
from _pydevd_bundle.pydevd_trace_dispatch import (
File "/home/www/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_trace_dispatch.py", line 63, in 
delete_old_compiled_extensions()
File "/home/www/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_trace_dispatch.py", line 18, in delete_old_compiled_extensions
import _pydevd_bundle_ext
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pydevd_bundle_ext'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Which PyCharm and Python versions do you use?